# Populate ComboBox with External List

Tags: c#, string, data-binding, external

So I have a program and an API. Within my API I have a list of type String stored which holds all the values that I want to be displayed in the ComboBox in the actual program.

My ComboBox is named: Cloud_ComboBox and is in the class "Cloud" in my API

and my list named: CloudType

I have no idea on how to achieve this, I have looked online already but not yet found a solution.

Thanks!

Edit: What I had already attempted but failed to work:

Within the program:

```
private void Cloud_ComboBox_DropDownOpened(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Cloud_ComboBox.ItemsSource = CloudType;
    }
```

Within the XAML:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CloudType}"
```

Comment: Which UI are you using? WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET or ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: Show the code, so we can see what have you tried and what didn't work as expected.

Comment: @walther Have now updated question

Comment: You're trying this two binding statements at the same time? Do you get any error message or how does it behave? Can you verify that your source collection actually does have items during debugging?

Answer (score 0):

The first is a very strange way to do it, and I wouldn't be surprised if it didn't work.  You should set ItemsSource once on window initialization.

The second should work if the DataContext is set properly.  Without seeing a little more code it may be difficult to say the best way to get the binging working.